# How to match last object in reducer array of objects and add or modify property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux

I have in my reducer array of objects. I want to update last object in array and check if has items property then just concat new items if not then create it with action.payload.items.

Here is code :

```
case SET_CATEGORIES_SEARCH_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.hash]: {
          ...state[action.payload.hash],
          [state[action.payload.hash][action.payload.name]]: [state[action.payload.hash][action.payload.name]].map((elem, index) => {
            if (index === action.payload.position) {
              elem = { ...elem };
              elem['items'] = elem['items'] ? elem['items'].concat(action.payload.items) : action.payload.items;
            }
            return elem;
          }),
        },
      };
```

And here is gist: https://gist.github.com/Jalson1982/116dec13f7070e7753fce018548c2770

Problem with this code is that it does not work :) it does not update last object in array . Any advice or help on this?

Comment: Check your `[state[action.payload.hash][action.payload.name]]` because it is a key and you are also mapping. What type of value it is? You are probably want `[action.payload.name]: ...`

Comment: [state[action.payload.hash][action.payload.name]] should be array
 [
{searchTerm:“cheese”, filter:[],items:[......]},
{searchTerm:“cheese”,filter:[“bio],items:[...]},
{searchTerm:“cheese”,filter:[“bio”,“nogluten”],items:[.....]},
{searchTerm:“cheese”,filter:[“nogluten”],items:[...],
{searchTerm:“cheese”, filter:[],items:[......]}
]

Comment: How can an array be a key of an abject? Maybe it can be, in that case why?

Comment: This is results i get:
categories:
[object Object]: [{…}]
categories: {}
categories_search: [{…}]
next_available_pickup_time: {timeSlots: "15.00:16.00"}
standard_header: {}

It creates new property and it should update categories_search

Comment: It isn't clear to me. Can you please add a sample object to your question?

Comment: It creates me object like this:
categories: {
[object Object]: [{…}]
categories: {}
categories_search: [{…}]
next_available_pickup_time: {timeSlots: "15.00:16.00"}
standard_header: {}
}
and it should add items into categories_search

Comment: Hmm, that looks completely unrelated to the question(hash, position, items etc.).